# Creating a new Team Project in VS2013 from existing Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

Can anyone tell me where the option for creating a new team project from an existing team project has disappeared too?

The process seems to be missing this step.

I can create a new Team Project, but the option to branch form an existing one is no longer available?

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: You do realise that this is a totally dysfunctional feature to use? Why would you want to start from scratch on builds, work items, bugs and tests? Do you no longer fix bugs still open on that codebase?

Comment: Because We have a template solution that we use for each project. Within this solution we then branch releases.